# Is there a way to get the login credentials held by a browser?

Tags: browser, authentication

I'm pretty sure the answer to this is no because it would be a major security hole. But if a user has logged in to a website using their browser, and then tell our desktop app to read an XML file from that website, is there a way to use the credentials the browser has so they do not need to give us the username & password?

thanks - dave

Comment: Preferably any but something that works on some would be better than nothing. thanks - dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible to get the password from Basic-Auth in javascript, as it would be a rather large security issue. However, if the browser learned about a basic-auth username/password pair, it will send it with every request to the matching domain, so you might not even be force to know the password on the client as the browser is going to handle it.

If you have a custom authentication schema, you *could* save the username and password in a way that you can access it via javascript from a cookie, but I strongly advise you to **not** do that, as it would open the username / password to anyone being able to run javascript in your app context (e.g. via XSS) and would probably save the password in clear-text on the user's hard-disk. What you should use in this case is a token based system (like oauth) or one of the many single-sign-on systems out there, which use short-lived and signed cookies.

Comment: Hi. I may not have been clear. My application is a desktop application, not a web app. And what we're being asked to do is regardless of the login system (basic, digest, FBA), that the desktop app can read XML files if the user logged in via their browser.

Comment: So you want to live completely outside of a browser and only use the in-saved flight credentials of a random open browser window? That's not going to work unless you build plugins for each supported browser to give you the credentials. But if that should work for random websites, you'd still need to understand its authentication schema beforehand (passwords, cookies, ...). The only thing that comes to my mind is to instruct the browser itself to download files to the hard-disk (with user support) and then reading it from disk with your app.